# Displaying a pom.xml version in angular project

Tags: java, xml, angular, maven

I have an angular project as a maven module. I would like to display the version of my angular module contained in my pom.xml file.

`pom.xml`

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Angular-module</groupId>
  <artifactId>angular</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

<name>angular</name>
<description>The frontend of the project</description>

<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>

        <configuration>
            <nodeVersion>v6.9.1</nodeVersion>
            <npmVersion>4.0.3</npmVersion>
            <workingDirectory>./src/main</workingDirectory>
        </configuration>

        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>install node and npm</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>

            <execution>
                <id>npm install</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>npm</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>

            <execution>
                <id>npm run build</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>npm</goal>
                </goals>

                <configuration>
                    <arguments>run build</arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <webResources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>target/frontend</directory>
                </resource>
            </webResources>
            <packagingExcludes>
            </packagingExcludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Is there any way, I can get my angular module version `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`, in my angular app when I will build the module with maven?

Comment: In the war file you will probably find /META-INF/maven/{groupId}/{artifactId}/pom.properties, which include the version info. However, you can probably not read that from a JS script, so instead write the properties to another file using the maven-properties-plugin http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/write-project-properties-mojo.html

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look to this Maven documentation : **[Filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)**

> ### Filtering
>
> Variables can be included in your resources. These variables, denoted
>   by the `${...}` delimiters, can come from the system properties, your
>   project properties, from your filter resources and from the command
>   line.
>
> For example, if we have a resource `src/main/resources/hello.txt`
>   containing
>
> ```
> Hello ${name}
> ```